# Zero padding OFDM equalization

Tags: ofdm, equalization, fading-channel

In ZP-OFDM, The convolution is linear. it's different from CP-OFDM which is circular convolution leading to have one tap equalizer in frequency domain.

if I have a ZP-OFDM system, and we have a signal to transmit $X$ of length $M$ x $1$, after adding the zero padding, the resultant transmitted signal will be  $x$ of length $N$ x $1$.  where the received signal is:

$y = h*x + v$, where $h$,$x$,$v$,$*$ denote multi-path channel of length $L$ x $1$, transmitted signal of length $N$x$1$, AWGN, and convolution operation,  respectively.

to recover the transmitted signal from the received signal $y$, let the matrix $G$ to be the MMSE equalizer built based on the toeplitz matrix $H$ equivalent to $h$. so estimated signal $x$ = $Gy$.

The question which I couldn't get a clear answer for it, Is it better to built the matrix $G$ of size $M$x$N$ and multiply it directly with $y$ which is $N$x$1$,  resulting the transmitted signal of size $M$x$1$. **OR**, I start discard the part equivalent to the zero padding from $y$ to have the length of $M$x$1$ and then build the matrix $G$ of size $M$x$M$ to be multiplied with $y$ after removing the part equivalent into the zero padding?

In simulation, the first option gives slightly better performance and more stable. Why ? what is the explanation of each case?

**EDIT**

1- The length of the received signal $y$ is considered to be $N$x $1$, it means that the delay of channel is already discarded.

2- We considered the length of the guard interval to be longer than the channel delay

3- The toeplitz matrix $H$ and $G$ was built as following,

```
C = [h;zeros(N-L,1)]; 
R = [h(1), zeros(1,N-1)];
H = toeplitz(C,R);  
G = inv((1/SNRv(i))*eye(N) + (H')*H) * (H');
```

Comment: well, using more of the signal obviously gives you more information; using only a part of the signal that was "spread out" by the channel convolution loses energy and thus information. But I think you already know that, considering you understand how you need to work with the linear convolution, so where specifically does this question arise from?

Comment: Hi Marcus, I couldn't understand what you mean "using more of signal obviously gives more information and using only a part of the signal that was spread out by the channel convolution loses energy", Is there detailed reason for that or mathematical expression?  2- the question was arise based on my notice on the MATLAB simulation results.

Comment: @Fatima_Ali As I don't know how you designed your matrix $G$, this comment is possibly wrong.

By $y = h*x + v$, the output $y$ is of length $N+L-1$ and have $M+L-1$ non-zero elements$^{(1)}$  because of the $(N-M)\textrm{-length}$ zero-padding, which should be greater than $L$ for proper zero-padding designs. Hence, the information is spread within the length of $M+L-1 \leq N$. 

...

Comment: @Fatima_Ali By using $G$ of size $N$, you have the chance of be able to collect all the possible information and, therefore, better results than using $G$ of size $M$ where you have thrown away something. The performance difference depends on many things including but not limited to how padding $N-M$ is greater than delay spread $L$, what is thrown away by using $G$ of size $M$ and how $G$ are designed$^{(2)}$ .

$^{(1)}$ element is of general meaning.

$^{(2)}$ the "optimal" $G$ for size $M$ processing is not necessarily optimal for the case of size $N$.

Comment: @AlexTP I added the information you asked about into the question. Could you please reply me as an answer with more details "to accept your answer".

Comment: @Fatima_Ali you are creating ISI. I guess you simulated only one zero-padded OFDM symbol each time, nothing before and after it, right? Try sending three consecutive OFDM symbols over a channel having $L = N-M$, and decoding the middle one. Using $N$ elements mean the input of your equalizer contains the elements of the previous symbol and/or the next symbol. Using $M$ elements will avoid this ISI, and that is the purpose of ZP and CP. If you have already simulated consecutive symbols, my explanation above must have flaw somewhere.

Comment: @AlexTP I am transmitting 5 consecutive OFDM symbols, with number of subcarriers $M = 1024$, guard interval duration $N-M = 256$, channel length $L=128$